# How can Integrate of conjugate transpose in mathematica?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, geometry, webmathematica, mathematica-online

please help me to integrate this matrix in matematica:

0        ConjugateTranspose[u[x,t]] (u_x)[x,t]+I vx,t[x,t]      0
-ConjugateTranspose[u[x,t]] (u^(1,0))[x,t]-I vx,t[x,t]   0       0
0                         0                                           0

u_x and v_x denote the diferentiate with respect to x.I dont know how can integrate the complex conjugate with mathematica.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Differentiation with respect to x is written `D[f[x,t],x]` . But what should: `(u^(1,0))`  and `vx,t[x,t]` mean? And what are matrizes and what scalars?

Comment: To input mathematical equations and formulaes into stackexchange.com make use of an appropriate browser like Firefox and make use of [mathjax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference): The transpose of a scalar is the same scalar. There has to be a matrix for the `Transpose` built-in.